# "Item" schema is not found even i required that model.(mongoose,Node.js)

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I am trying to run hook of 'remove' in label schema.***"Item.find is not a function"*** this is the error which I got.
But 'Item' schema is not found.This "**require**"  works fine on other models.Here it is not working.

That error  might be occurs in `var Item = require('./Item');`

This is "**Label**" schema.

```
  var mongoose = require('mongoose');
    var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
    var Item = require('./Item');
    var List = require('./List');

    // created schema for Item
    var labelSchema = new Schema({
      label_title: {type: String},
      color_id:{type: String, required: true},
      created_at: Date,
      updated_at: Date,
      marked : { Boolean ,default:false },
      _board: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref:'Board'}
    });

    //-----------------Hook--
    labelSchema.post('remove',function(doc,next){

      Label.remove({_id:this._id}).then(function(data){
        console.log("successfuly removed label");
      }).catch(function(error){console.log(error);
      })

    //-----remove label from all items
       // console.log("ITEM", Item);
        Item.find({},function(error,items){
          items.forEach(function(item){
            Item.findByIdAndUpdate(item._id,
              { "$pullAll": { "label" : [{ "label_id" : this._id }]} },function(error,result){
                if(result)console.log("successfully removed");
                else console.log("not removed");
              })
          })
    })
    });


    var Label = mongoose.model('Label', labelSchema);
    module.exports = Label;
```

What should I do?